# Parallax scrolling an active element

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set up a parallax scrolling effect on one of the pages of my app, similar to the one shown here: http://y2bd.me/blog/2014/03/18/creating-a-parallax-scrolling-effect-on-windows-phone/

The example is using a two-row grid, with a transparent first row covering the image used for the parallax effect. The problem is: I need a fully functional Map control instead of a simple image - and by "fully functional" I mean using touch gestures for scrolling, zooming and highlighting pushpins. However, none of the touch gestures can "get through" the grid on top of the Map control.

I know events can be "bubbled" up the visual tree, so a control's PARENT can handle them instead of the control itself, but my case involves controls on two separate branches of the tree (both placed on the same grid row).
Is there a way to "redirect" events on one control to a different control's event handler or somehow trigger them differently?
Or is there a different/better way of getting that kind of a scrolling effect?

Comment: Oh this sounds interesting, do you have a visual example of what you're trying to do in relation to a map with the effect? I haven't had an opportunity to mess with much parallax yet but am a fan of the effect if used well.

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. What I'd like to achieve is a page with a small map panel, that can then be "stretched" down to the maximum allowed height. Something like the example I mentioned in my question.